# Expected value of the first event in the binary random process

Tags: probability, means

$U_n$ be an iid binary random process with $P_r\{ U_{n}=1\}=P_r\{U_n=-1\}=0.5 , \forall n$. what is the expected value of the  $U_0$?

I think $U_0$ may be the first time in this binary random process,but i am not sure that  the $E[ U_0]$ will be $0.5$ just because the probability of $1$ and $-1$ are both $0.5$.

Comment: Is there any reason then to expect $EU_0=0.5$? Why not $=0.5\times1+0.5\times(-1)=0$?

Comment: oh you are right.i miss some thinking